# Как отцентрировать блок внутри блока с абсолютным позиционированием?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Написал для примера такой код:

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #0f0;
}

.onea {
  float: left;
  position: static;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f0f;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.twoa {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff0;
}

.threea {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f70;
}

.foura {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.oneaa {
  background: #095;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="onea">111</div>
    <div class="twoa">222</div>
    <div class="threea">333</div>
    <div class="foura">
      <div class="oneaa">111111111111</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Получается такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отцентрировать блок внутри блока с абсолютным позиционированием? Т.е. блок с классом `oneaa` должен вертикально отцентрироваться внутри блока с классом `foura`.

Если можно, приведите несколько вариантов вертикального центрирования данного блока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Решение 1

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #0f0;
}

.onea {
  float: left;
  position: static;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f0f;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.twoa {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff0;
}

.threea {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f70;
}

.foura {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.oneaa {
  background: #095;
  text-align: center;
  top: calc(50% - .5em);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="onea">111</div>
    <div class="twoa">222</div>
    <div class="threea">333</div>
    <div class="foura">
      <div class="oneaa">111111111111</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## Объяснение 1

Я добавил к `.oneaa` пропорцию `top`, со значением: `calc(50% - 0.5em)`, это конструкция значит это: подвинуть вниз на 50% - половина размера шрифта. А чтобы `top` работал я добавил пропорцию `position: absolute;` и т.к. один из родителей имеет `position: relative`, позиционирование ведётся относительно этого родителя. И также добавил `width: 100%;`, чтобы блок был во всю ширину родительского блока.

## Решение 2

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #0f0;
}

.onea {
  float: left;
  position: static;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f0f;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.twoa {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff0;
}

.threea {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f70;
}

.foura {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.oneaa {
  background: #095;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(calc(50px - .5em));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="onea">111</div>
    <div class="twoa">222</div>
    <div class="threea">333</div>
    <div class="foura">
      <div class="oneaa">111111111111</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## Объяснение 2

С помощью `transform`, я подвинул элемент на 50 пикселей вниз (это половина высоты от родительского блока `.foura`) и от 50 пиклесей я также отнял половину высоты `.oneaa`, т.к. вы нигде не задаёте высоту `.oneaa`, то её высоту составляет шрифт, а `1em` = 1 кратный размер шрифта в пикселях, то есть берём половину `0.5em` и получаем ровно половину от блока `.oneaa`.

## Решение 3

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #0f0;
}

.onea {
  float: left;
  position: static;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f0f;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.twoa {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff0;
}

.threea {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f70;
}

.foura {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.oneaa {
  background: #095;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: calc(50px - .5em);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="onea">111</div>
    <div class="twoa">222</div>
    <div class="threea">333</div>
    <div class="foura">
      <div class="oneaa">111111111111</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## Объяснение 3

Можно тоже самое сделать с `margin-top`, подвинуть вниз на половину высоту блока и т.д., но я не рекомендую такой способ, он менее производителен чем `transform: translate`. Это будет более, если вы будете двигать свои блоки, или фиксировать их на экране. Но если блоки у вас абсолютно точно будет статичные, тогда можете спокойно использовать этот способ, т.к. он короче (и красивей /imho) и поддерживается более большим кол-вом браузеров.

Answer (score 0):

> Как отцентрировать блок внутри блока с абсолютным позиционированием? Т.е. блок с классом oneaa должен вертикально отцентрироваться внутри блока с классом foura.

Нужно такое?

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #0f0;
}

.onea {
  float: left;
  position: static;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f0f;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.twoa {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff0;
}

.threea {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f70;
}

.foura {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  /* Добавить */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.oneaa {
  background: #095;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="onea">111</div>
    <div class="twoa">222</div>
    <div class="threea">333</div>
    <div class="foura">
      <div class="oneaa">111111111111</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А как именно ваше решение работает? Зачем: `flex-direction: column;`? Такие вопросы возникают у меня при виде вашего решения, поэтому и нужно писать исчерпывающие ответы, чтобы другие пользователя смогли разобраться в вашем ответе. Между прочим, я хочу услышать ответы на поставленные выше вопросы, потому что и вправду интересно как работает ваше решение.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #0f0;
}

.onea {
  float: left;
  position: static;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f0f;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.twoa {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff0;
}

.threea {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f70;
}

.foura {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.oneaa {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #095;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="onea">111</div>
  <div class="twoa">222</div>
  <div class="threea">333</div>
  <div class="foura">
    <div class="oneaa">111111111111</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

или:

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #0f0;
}

.onea {
  float: left;
  position: static;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f0f;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.twoa {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff0;
}

.threea {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f70;
}

.foura {
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.oneaa {
  align-self: center;
  background: #095;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="onea">111</div>
  <div class="twoa">222</div>
  <div class="threea">333</div>
  <div class="foura">
    <div class="oneaa">111111111111</div>
  </div>
</div>
```